# 4 Contact Form 7 fields in one line

Tags: css, wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

I am trying to make a contact form that include 4 fields one after one in same line, and in tablet or mobile, the fields will be one under one in 100% width.

actually i have tried a lot, and i got confused from the css.

this is the css that i use:

```
.one-half,
.one-third {
position: relative;
margin-right: 4%;
float: right;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.one-half { width: 48%; }
.one-third { width: 30.66%; }

.last {
margin-left: 0 !important;
clear: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.one-half, .one-third {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
}
}
```

the form is:

```
<div class="one-half">
[text* Fullname placeholder "full name"]
</div>
<div class="one-half">
[tel* phone placeholder "phone"]
</div>
<div class="one-half">
[email* email placeholder "email"]
</div>
<div class="one-half last">
[submit "SEND"] </div>
```

Comment: `float: right;margin-right: 4%;` must be `float: left;margin-left: 4%;` for dekstop. also you want same to display field on dekstop in single line and on responsive this should be on one by one underneath?

Comment: how about this ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vRzwBM

Comment: why not use the [Smart Grid-layout for CF7 extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) which allows you to build a a grid layout form using a UI editor instead.  You can easily create 4 columns in a single row and place your tags in each column to get the result you're looking form.

Comment: many thanks! work great

Answer (score 1):

give these properties to parent div of the element which you give float LIKE

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="one-half">
    [text* Fullname placeholder "full name"]
    </div>
    <div class="one-half">
    [tel* phone placeholder "phone"]
    </div>
    <div class="one-half">
    [email* email placeholder "email"]
    </div>
    <div class="one-half last">
    [submit "SEND"] </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
container:after{
    content:'';
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Your e-mail*: <span style="display:inline-block;">[email* your-email]</span> <span style="display:inline-block;">[submit "Send"]</span>
```